# How to install PgAdmin 4 on Ubuntu 20

Tags: pgadmin-4, ubuntu-20.04

I've installed PgAdmin III through "Ubuntu Software" manager but it is crashing. I've tried to "sudo apt-get update" and then, sudo apt-get pgadmin4. I get a message that this package doesn't exist. I've tried all the things I've found related to Ubuntu 20 and some for Ubuntu 19.